# How to Altering the Calendar Overlay when Max Entry detected for every time slot

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, calendar

> Please follow these steps:
>
> 1. you need to create a view to represent your calendar (You'll need to declare your filters).
> 2. create a calendar overlay, in this example, I filtered "ms-acal-item" because it is where the calendar items per hour is located, you'll need to open the IE Developer Tool by pressing F12, and trace the ... to get the exact value getElementsByClassName.

```
var times = [
            "7:00 am - 7:30 am ", 
            "7:30 am - 8:00 am ", 
            "8:00 am - 8:30 am ", 
            "8:30 am - 9:00 am ",
            "9:00 am - 9:30 am ",
            "9:30 am - 10:00 am ",
            "10:00 am - 10:30 am ",
            "10:30 am - 11:00 am ",
            "11:00 am - 11:30 am ",
            "11:30 am - 12:00 pm ",
            "12:00 pm - 12:30 pm ",
            "12:30 pm - 1:00 pm ",
            "1:00 pm - 1:30 pm ",
            "1:30 pm - 2:00 pm ",
            "2:00 pm - 2:30 pm ",
            "2:30 pm - 3:00 pm ",
            "3:00 pm - 3:30 pm ",
            "3:30 pm - 4:00 pm ",
            "4:00 am - 4:30 am ",
            "4:30 am - 5:00 am ",
            "5:00 pm - 5:30 pm ",
            "5:30 pm - 6:00 pm ",
            "6:00 pm - 6:30 pm ",
            "6:30 pm - 7:00 pm "
            ];

function ApplyColor() {

    var nodes, iCount, TimeIdentifier;

    for (x = 0; x < times.length; x++){
        TimeIdentifier = times[x];
        console.log(times[x]);
        nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-acal-item");

        iCount = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

            if (nodes[i].outerHTML.indexOf(TimeIdentifier) != -1) {

                console.log(nodes[i].outerHTML);
                var parts = nodes[i].outerHTML.split(TimeIdentifier);

                iCount += 1;

                // Set the maximim number of entries to make it red
                if (iCount >= 4)
                {
                    if (parts[1])
                    {
                        var color = GetCalendarColour("red");
                        nodes[i].style.background = color;
                    }
                }
            }
        }                       
    }
}

function GetCalendarColour(desc) {
    var colour;
    switch (desc.toLowerCase()) {

        case "red":
            colour = "rgb(255,000,000)";
            break;

        default:
            colour = "";
    }
    return colour;
}

window.setInterval(function () {
    ApplyColor();
}, 500);
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Hi @RobG, actually I made the title as a question :), but it's already answered. I'm thinking of maybe someone is looking for it. I tried looking almost 3 days, but I didn't find any. So I posted my effort to help others. Thanks

Comment: The entirety of your question should be in the question and should not depend on the title to make sense. If you're posting an answer to a question that you think is helpful, you should post it as a question, then provide an answer as an answer and accept it. You might want to read [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Posting good questions and answers takes effort.

Answer (score 0):

> Correction for var times
>               "3:30 pm - 4:00 pm ",
>              "4:00 am - 4:30 am ",
>              "4:30 am - 5:00 am ",
>              "5:00 pm - 5:30 pm ",
>   should be pm. Thanks

```
var times = [
            "7:00 am - 7:30 am ", 
            "7:30 am - 8:00 am ", 
            "8:00 am - 8:30 am ", 
            "8:30 am - 9:00 am ",
            "9:00 am - 9:30 am ",
            "9:30 am - 10:00 am ",
            "10:00 am - 10:30 am ",
            "10:30 am - 11:00 am ",
            "11:00 am - 11:30 am ",
            "11:30 am - 12:00 pm ",
            "12:00 pm - 12:30 pm ",
            "12:30 pm - 1:00 pm ",
            "1:00 pm - 1:30 pm ",
            "1:30 pm - 2:00 pm ",
            "2:00 pm - 2:30 pm ",
            "2:30 pm - 3:00 pm ",
            "3:00 pm - 3:30 pm ",
            "3:30 pm - 4:00 pm ",
            "4:00 pm - 4:30 pm ",
            "4:30 pm - 5:00 pm ",
            "5:00 pm - 5:30 pm ",
            "5:30 pm - 6:00 pm ",
            "6:00 pm - 6:30 pm ",
            "6:30 pm - 7:00 pm "
            ];
```